# SPARQL wikidata query: Obtain number of languages that associated wikipedia article is available in

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Is it possible to use SPARQL on wikidata to extract the number of languages of a wikipedia article associated with a wikidata item?

I am new to SPARQL and wikidata. I have tried to find examples online, but no luck so far. I am able to extract the url for the wikipedia article. But I wonder if it is possible to count the number of languages for which the url exists. Here is my code so far:

```
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?museum ?museumLabel ?article WHERE {
  ?museum wdt:P17 wd:Q39;   # countries                  
          wdt:P31 ?type.
          ?type (wdt:P279*) wd:Q207694.


         # If available, get the "en" entry, use native language as fallback:
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,de". }
  # get wikipedia article in english       
  OPTIONAL {
      ?article schema:about ?museum .
      ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
      FILTER (SUBSTR(str(?article), 1, 25) = "https://en.wikipedia.org/")
    }
}
order by ?museum
```

I would like to add another column to my output that gives me the number of languages a wikipedia article exists in.

Comment: https://github.com/Daniel-Mietchen/ideas/issues/849 would help you if the full Wikipedia articles were available as RDF literals, but as they are not, your goal cannot currently be achieved.

Comment: That's too bad. Is it possible to count the number of languages a wikipedia article is available in? For example, if a museum has wikipedia pages in English, French and German, I would like to get '3' as an outcome.

Comment: Well, it's possible to count the number of languages for which there's a langtagged literal for a given predicate within a given SPARQL endpoint — but that count won't necessarily be the same in DBpedia  — or in DBpedia Live, or in any other endpoints — as in Wikipedia. If you rewrite your question (or ask a new one) with this focus, I'll post a query that will get this answer from a chosen endpoint.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have reformulated the question.

Comment: https://w.wiki/6nF cf. https://w.wiki/6n, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Sitelinks

Comment: Thanks, Stanislav. This looks great. How do I modify the command such that it spits out the # of wikipedia articles of the museums from the search I posted above (as opposed to the # of wikipedia articles of 'life')?

Comment: I would like to do exactly this: count the languages, an article is available on wikipedia. Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?museum ?museumLabel (COUNT(DISTINCT ?article) as ?wiki_article_count) WHERE {
       ?museum wdt:P17 wd:Q39;   # countries                  
               wdt:P31 ?type.
               ?type (wdt:P279*) wd:Q207694.
       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,de". }
       OPTIONAL {
          ?article schema:about ?museum .
       }
}
GROUP BY ?museum ?museumLabel
ORDER BY DESC( ?wiki_article_count )
```

Further developing the query given in the question, one can obtain the number of linked wiki-pages (I am absolutely not sure about the nomenclature).

Please try the Wikidata Query Service here: https://w.wiki/334g

For example, one can see for the wikidata/wiki entry: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q194626 (Kunstmuseum Basel) (nomenclature remains unclear to me for now. Is it a wiki-entity?) 22 linked wiki-pages. That is 21 wikipedia-languages and one multilingual-site. See screenshot here:

[image]

I would be thankful for any comments on this answer and could improve this answer accordingly.